Show ColorPicker in popover on macOS
We can present the color picker in swiftUI easily.
ColorPicker("", selection: $selectedColor)

However, in my macOS app it looks ridiculous as it opens as a standalone view and is disconnected from the app.

What I would like to achieve is by tapping a button, color picker opens in popover, the same way as it opens in the Preview app.


You might be looking for a NSColorWell with the minimal style.
It looks like this:

Here I have wrapped this in a NSViewRepresentable:
struct MyColorPicker: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var color: Color
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSColorWell {
        let colorWell = NSColorWell(style: .minimal)
        colorWell.color = NSColor(color)
        
        context.coordinator.startObservingColorChange(of: colorWell)
        return colorWell
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSColorWell, context: Context) {
        nsView.color = NSColor(color)
        context.coordinator.colorDidChange = {
            color = Color(nsColor: $0)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    @MainActor
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var colorDidChange: ((NSColor) -> Void)?
        
        private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
        
        func startObservingColorChange(of colorWell: NSColorWell) {
            cancellable = colorWell.publisher(for: \.color).sink { [weak self] in
                self?.colorDidChange?($0)
            }
        }
    }
}

Usage:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var color: Color = .white
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            color
            MyColorPicker(color: $color).fixedSize()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


This looks and works perfectly what I wanted. Thanks man

The standalone view is not functionally disconnected from the app itself. The window has more advanced color picking features rather than just the small dropdown. I have an iMac and it does the same thing (I get annoyed too). Hope this helps! :)

To me it feels disconnected since it doesn't appear as a modal window on top of the app (like the Save As dialog does), but is rather shown somewhere randomly on the screen (I don't have full screen app). I understand there are more features in current setup, but I really only need basic color palette.
